# Reading HDF5 files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdf5

Is there a way to read HDF5 files using the Scala version of Spark?

It looks like it can be done in Python (via Pyspark), but I can't find anything for Scala.

Comment: This might help you get you started. http://hdfgroup.org/wp/2015/03/from-hdf5-datasets-to-apache-spark-rdds/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a Hadoop `InputFormat`implementation for HDF5 because it is not capable of being arbitrarily split:

> Breaking the container into blocks is a bit like taking an axe and chopping it to pieces, severing blindly the content and the smart wiring in the process. The result is a mess, because there's no alignment or correlation between HDFS block boundaries and the internal HDF5 cargo layout or container support structure. [Reference](http://www.hdfgroup.org/pubs/papers/Big_HDF_FAQs.pdf)

The same site discusses the possibility of transforming HDF5 files to Avro files, thus enabling them to be read by Hadoop/Spark, but the [PySpark](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201407.mbox/%3CCAJgQjQ8yx+EByOoODUBn8kSStjNESjs4N=w=zQOeqiEWf-p18A@mail.gmail.com%3E) example you alluded to is probably a simpler way to go, but as the linked document mentions, there are a number of technical challenges that need to be addressed to efficiently and effectively work with HDF5 documents in Hadoop/Spark.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new product that can talk to HDF5 from Apache Spark via Scala:

https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5-enterprise-support/hdf5-connector-for-apache-spark/

With the above product, you can open and read HDF5 like below in Scala:

```
//
// HOW TO RUN:
//
// $spark-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT-bin-hdf5s-0.0.1/bin/spark-shell -i demo.scala

import org.hdfgroup.spark.hdf5._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL HDF5 example").getOrCreate()

// We assume that HDF5 files (e.g., GSSTF_NCEP.3.2008.12.31.he5) are 
// under /tmp directory. Change the path name ('/tmp') if necessary.
val df=spark.read.option("extension", "he5").option("recursion", "false").hdf5("/tmp/", "/HDFEOS/GRIDS/NCEP/Data Fields/SST")

// Let's print some values from the dataset.
df.show()

// The output will look like below.
//
//+------+-----+------+
//|FileID|Index| Value|
//+------+-----+------+
//|     0|    0|-999.0|
//|     0|    1|-999.0|
//|     0|    2|-999.0|
//...

System.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628753/read-hdf5-files-from-tar-gz-compressed-file-in-scala-in-spark/47956913#47956913) has an example on how to read multiple hdf5 files (compressed as .tar.gz) from the Million Song Dataset and extract each file's features to end up with a Spark RDD where each element of the RDD is an Array of features of each hdf5 file.